# Same PasswordResetToken for both aspnet identity and aspnet core identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

We have 2 application using same DB, one is web ASP.NET MVC web application which uses `Aspnet.Identity` and another is .net core Web API application with `AspNetCore.Identity`. Token generated from .net core application for reset password using `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync` is not accepted by MVC application.

Below is configuration of MVC application.

```
var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
{
   manager.UserTokenProvider = 
   new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
}
```

Configuration of .net core

```
services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(options => options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = "ASP.NET Identity")
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RepositoryContext>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
   .AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<IdentityUser>>("ASP.NET Identity")
```

Comment: Two different libraries based on two different platforms. You can't do one thing from Asp.net Framework and try apply it to Asp.net Core... It just won't work, that's just the way I see it.

Comment: @MosiaThabo We have already achieved most of things like Login,Change password.

Comment: Those are pretty easy to do because they persist in the database. But the Tokens are generated real-time and confirmed real time. They are not stored... Hence, I believe the issue is with the approach each identity framework takes to generating those Tokens. I also believe you can't create a ChangePasswordToken on AspNetCore and use that same Token in AspNet? have you done that successfully?

Comment: Overall, I think you just need to extend the default Identity Framework (UserManager or SignInManager) and make sure they generate and verify the code the same way. Otherwise, they aren't the same thing.